# Image URLs for Umbraco on Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an Umbraco (7.7.2) website on Azure and I've configured it to store images in blob storage (using `Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureBlobFileSystem`)

Then I my page I have (simplified):

```
 var image = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("image");
 <meta property="og:image" content="@image.Url" />
```

Which creates this HTML:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="/media/1030/image1.jpg" />
```

The code works fine and shows the images, but I wonder if I should have the URL to Blob storage instead?

What will happen now when a request goes for /media/1030/image1.jpg? Will it hit the app service everytime before reading the file blob storage or will it hit the blob storage directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I don't understand your question, but I feel the need to point out that the AzureBlobFileSystem package provides a [Virtual Path Provider](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure/blob/develop/src/UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure/FileSystemVirtualPathProvider.cs). This essentially re-routes any calls from /media/... to your blob storage container, so the images you are supplying are actually coming from your blob storage container and not the file system.

If I remember correctly, this is all configurable, so you can either change this to serve your standard blob storage URL's, or you can use one of the add-on CDN packages to serve Azure CDN URL's, if you would prefer.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That was exactly my question. So how can I make sure that I have the correct settings? I mean how I can make sure that when there is a request for /media/1020/image1.jpg it doesn't go through application before hitting the CDN?

Comment: In a way, it does. The VPP is set up on the application, and when you receive a request for a certain path (e.g. ./media/...) it is handled by that VPP code instead of as a route or file, like an internal redirect. If you want to see if what you're hitting is a blob or a local file, I'd say the best option is to either check your logs or check the file system to see if newly-created media items are going into the blob, or are being put on your file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike :)

Comment: In Chrome tools you should be able to right click the virtual url path and choose Open in new tab.  I think you will then see the true path to the blob.

Comment: @wingyip Not necessarily. If a VPP is used the user will see the standard "/media/1000/image.jpg" URL at root, and not the direct URL to the blob image. The VPP is essentially an internal redirect from that blob URL to an internal one.